# How do I process .asp extensions using the .Net handler?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, iis-7, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have an older classic ASP website that I am migrating over to IIS7.5.  I don't feel like installing classic ASP on the server, and so I just want the .asp files to be treated as if they were .aspx files.

How do I go about doing this in IIS7.5?

EDIT: To clarify, I am NOT asking how to get classic ASP code to work under .Net.  I am just asking how to map the .ASP file extension to be handled by the .net runtime.  I will upgrade the code in the .asp files to .net.

**EDIT:**

I gave up and ended up installing classic ASP, as I couldn't get the mapping to work (received a combination of 404.17 and 404.3 errors).  I marked David Lively's answer as correct as it was the most detailed and helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**That's not going to work**. Aspnet_isapi.DLL, which handles executing ASP.NET applications, doesn't understand classic ASP, and will try to parse the classic VBScript code as .NET VBScript.

The only way this is feasible is if you have no (and I mean **ABSOLUTELY NONE**) classic ASP code in your .ASP pages.

**If that is the case**,  you can map the .ASP extension to aspnet_isapi in IIS manager.

1. Open inetmgr.
2. Select the website
3. In the Feature View panel, select "Handler Mappings" [image]
4. Add a mapping for .ASP to `C:\Windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll` (assuming you're using ASP.NET 2.x).

Again, if you have **any** code in your .asp pages, this will cause a glorious, technicolor failure for every .ASP page.

Another option is to use a rewrite engine (we use [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/)) to change the file extension of incoming requests from from .asp to .aspx.

Why don't you want to install classic ASP on the server? It works just fine in parallel with ASP.NET.

**edit**

It's actually called "handler mappings." See image above.

Comment: I'm just trying to keep the server clean.

Comment: When you say "add a mapping to .ASP" do you mean: "Add Managed Handler", "Add Script Map", "Add Wildcard Script Map", or "Add Module Mapping"?

Comment: @Alex: it's not like it's some third-party software. This is ASP from Microsoft, and it's what your existing pages are written in. What's the problem with installing the software necessary to get your job done?

Comment: @John: Maybe there's no problem.  But there are 20 other sites on this box not using classic ASP, and this is a small mostly static website that will likely be retired from production within 6 months.  So it just makes me feel dirty to install classic ASP support just so I can server a page with a server side include that I will delete in a few months.  But maybe I am being overly sensitive about this.  I just thought it would be easier to just have .asp pages processed by the .net runtime.

Comment: @Alex: I have no idea why you thought the two were that similar, but they're not. You can't have Classic ASP pages served by .NET. Period.

Comment: Are these purely HTML pages, or do they have server-side features? If they're HTMl then you don't need them to be processed by ASP.NET. If they have server-side features, then **it's just not going to work because they are two independent and incompatible server-side languages**.

Comment: @John: They are 99% html.  The only server side code is an include for the header and footers, and the occasional 301 redirect.  The site itself is only 20 pages, so my plan was to just re-code any (and all) pages that error'd .  I don't want to change the extension due to search engine reasons.

Comment: @Alex: that 1% is fatal. **it will not work**. If they're this simple, then rewrite them as .aspx pages, and have the originals redirect to the new ones (302 permanent redirect).

Comment: @Alex if the headers and footers contain **any** ASP code, this still won't work. If, however, they are pure HTML and you have the Server-Side Include feature installed, this should be fine.

Comment: @John: At this point, I just want to know how to to have my .asp file extensions mapped to the .net handler in IIS7.5.  I appreciate the extra feedback, but it doesn't help me in answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work. ASP and ASP.NET are different things.

ASP.NET doesn't support VBScript, for instance. It also doesn't support includes.

Comment: This will be an .aspx page with an .asp extension.

Comment: @Alex: please update your question with that information. And if this is your downvote, that's not what they're for.

Comment: +1 to counteract stupid downvote, since his question didn't explicitly state this crucial counterintuitive fact.

Comment: @John: Sorry for the downvote.  I thought they were to indicate that "This answer is not useful"?

Comment: @David: The question was: "How do I process .asp extensions using the .Net handler?".

Comment: @Alex: the answer wasn't useful because you didn't ask your real question. There's a really big difference between what you asked and what you intended.

Comment: @John: I think if you read the question literally, I am asking exactly what I want.  I want to know how to have IIS7.5 handle files with an .asp extension using the .aspx handler.  That's it.  I think everyone read too much into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I Think ASP is not enabled by defualt in the IIS7, so you might have to enable it by using windows control panel Control:

Panel/Programs/Turn On/Off Windows Features/Internet Information Services/WorldWideWeb Services/ Application Development Features / [ASP][ISAPI FILTERS] etc...

Then choose all features you need.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You must follow the start menu as given below to get VS2010 command prompt.

1. Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Sutdio Command Prompt(2010)
2. Right Click on the Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010) and select Run as Administrator in case of Windows 7 and Vista
3. then apply aspnet_regiis.exe -i