# New file type for JavaScript content on IIS 7.5 integrated mode in order to render it

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms, httpmodule

I want to create a new file type (for example .jsrender). Inside this file, there is some JavaScript code, but also some code nuggets like `<%= txt1.ClientID %>` that have to be rendered before it's outputted.

How can I achieve this functionality? Also, how can I reference it? Can I do the following?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/myjs.jsrender" runat="server" />
```

Will it work?

Also, I am going to reference it from code-behind file like below:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.Page, 
    typeof(Page), 
    "JQueryUITimepickerAddonAjaxminJs",
    String.Format("<script src='{0}' type='text/javascript' defer='defer'></script>", 
        ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/timepicker_addon/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.ajaxmin.jsrender")), 
    false);
```

Do you think it will be rendered before it's outputted?

I know that we can create HttpModules for IIS, but I don't know what to do for this kind of functinality.

Thanks!

Comment: looks like not an attraction topic? :S

Answer (score 1):

You just need to map that file extension to the ASP.Net handler. See the post below for doing that. Also look at his recommendation to use a rewrite to to just change the file extension dynamically.

[How do I process .asp extensions using the .Net handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659700/how-do-i-process-asp-extensions-using-the-net-handler)