# ASP .NET code in SVG?

Tags: asp.net, svg

I am looking for a way that I can add .SVG files to server-side code handlers or something, so that I can have server-side code handled in my .SVG files, without needing to change to the .ASPX file extension.

I know how to do this in PHP, just not in ASP .NET.

Comment: Depending on the version of IIS there's a little bit different ways to do it. See this post for IIS 7. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659700/how-do-i-process-asp-extensions-using-the-net-handler/4659767#4659767

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement an ASP.NET HTTP handler. See [HTTP Handlers and HTTP Modules Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx).

Basically, you create an implementation of the `System.Web.IHttpHandler` interface and register it in `web.config` (you can register it for any URL pattern you like, so you can serve `*.svg` URLs and have the handler execute your logic).

If you're running an older IIS version, you will also need to add a file extension mapping to IIS configuration. For IIS 7, all you need to do to add the mapping is to register your handler in `web.config`.